# Questions about connecting a passive infra-red sensor to the USB port

Tags: usb, driver, software, hardware

So, we are linking a sensor to a computer via USB, using a female USB connector and male USB wires. The sensor is connected to a circuit with 3 pins, vcc, ground, output signal. If I would want the signal to be processed by the computer to output " I sense someone" when ever the sensor fires, what would I need to do? basic questions to answer are:

- How would the computer understand the signal from the usb? Using a device driver? or something else(please specify)
- I read that the usb can burnout if you are careless about the energy you input on it, so what is this healthy energy( Vcc , Amps) range? ( and how do I achieve this?)

P.S.: my professor told me that the device driver is only used for driving a certain device... idk if he is right or not :\ this totally contradicts my knowledge about device drivers, I know that everything you insert to a computer that has an input to be understand needs a device driver( ei, mouse, keyboard) it's hard for me to believe that the computer controls the mouse since, it can't because that is senseless(because the standard mouse is only for input :)

P.S.: the sensor is a Passive infrared sensor, with 2 jumper modes, to fire only once every X time while their is movement. and to fire constantly which there is movement.

Comment: USB doesn't use 3 wires. USB host controllers will usually shut down if you draw too much power. you will be using a driver whether you know it or not, but it will probably be a standard driver in serial mode.

Comment: I meant the Sensor has 3 pins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a device that has USB controller capability, or you can use an external chip. The actual device I would recommend depends on what kind of output the sensor has. Is this output On or off? If it's something so simple, I highly recommend using an ATTINY device like [this](http://www.recursion.jp/avrcdc/cdc-232.html). ATTiny simulates USB and works nicely without too much complexity.

However, if your IR sensor needs an ADC and some processing, you can use an MSP430, PIC, Cortex M3/M4 and many others depending on whether you need some processing of that signal.

Lets assume that you have the USB connectivity. In reality you need to choose a class for your USB device and for this I recommend CDC since it basically opens a COM port on the computer and you can send data as it arrives, then process it with any kind of program you like.

Comment: The sensor is
http://www.parallax.com/Store/Sensors/ObjectDetection/tabid/176/ProductID/793/List/0/Default.aspx?SortField=ProductName,ProductName

Comment: @RalphJaredTeng: Yes. So it's just a high or low signal. ATTiny is good here if no processing is required.

Comment: what exactly is ATTiny for? sorry im an IT student and I need this for our capstone(thesis) first part(planning stage), we defended successfully but we need to fix the suggestions and remarks from the professors(panel members).

Comment: @RalphJaredTeng: It's a microcontroller from Atmel to which USB software emulation was added, despite the fact that it doesn't have any USB controller per se. This works well for low intensity situations where not much or any processing on the microcontroller is needed (like your case). Google the name and you'll find a lot of info.

Comment: so that the input that i will pass to the computer is in some kind of protocol(something like a protocol)?
also would I need to create a device driver? our professor is countering that, with my knowledge, i know that every device needs a device driver if its going to communicate with the computer in input or output or both.  

thank you again for the quick and helpful answers Gustavo

Comment: @RalphJaredTeng: The ATTiny already has everything for the USB level. All you need is to send the input bit to the USB stack (should be examples) and open a terminal on the USB COM port.

Comment: What Gustavo means is that for low to moderate bandwidth arbitrary data, you can send it via a simulated serial interface carried over USB, leveraging standard USB-serial or USB-modem device drivers which have already been written.  Not sure I'd recommend the ATTINY over something with a real USB interface for a first attempt, unless you buy it already on a board with the USB-faking support components.  For another option, something like a traditional "Arduino" is not a *cost-efficient* USB device interface, but it may be a time/learning curve efficient one given the tools and support.

Comment: feasibility of the cost would be a problem for the capstone if we would use arduino( i think ). Thank you for both of your answers. I would discuss this to my thesis team and hope we make a decision tomorrow.

Comment: @RalphJaredTeng: Arduino is another solution as well. ATTINY is literally the smallest solution.

Comment: Id look at a FTDI development module , they have a few general io pins and could possibly power the sensor with minimal work..

Comment: @Gustavo Would I need to program the ATTiny? and also can I contact you for further help? Thanks again :)

Comment: Im thinking of this for the block diagram, p.s i needed multiple sensors so I used an OR gate
Sensors->Or gate-> ATTiny microcontroller-> USB connector-> USB communications device class -> Software -> screen

Comment: @RalphJaredTeng: I actually would recommend Arduino, since it's easier to get started on it. You can program it right off the bat, and for $30 it's hard to beat. ATTiny is good if you have knowledge to program it.

Comment: Which arduino would best suit the job though?, Thanks again for the reply Gustavo :)

Comment: Arduino Uno R3 works nicely.

Comment: Would Arduino Duemilanove be a good choice? or is it overkill for the simple job?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see your reply E-stackexchange is a little laggy ;)